# Sandboxing code on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, security, sandbox

I'm in the process of writing an application in C++ on Linux. The goal is to have it load dynamically linked libraries at run-time and to provide all the services that the libraries require. The main aim is to have it act as a black box where code loaded at run-time can not break out and damage the rest of the system.

I've never done anything like this before and am a little lost of the best method to take. If I load all the dynamically linked libraries under a special process and then use something like SELinux to limit the ability for the central daemon to do anything outside of its requirements would that seem like a reasonable solution?

The reason I ask is that I want to allow people to load code into this container application that then handles all the server side stuff for them, so things such as security, permissions, networking, logging etc are all provided with a simple, clean and cross platform API regardless of the version of UNIX that the container is running on.

Comment: `capabilities` can give you higher resolution to system privileges.  It's useful if you only need superuser access for a couple of very specific features.  [`setcap`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) is somewhat like `setuid`, but with capabilities instead.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.docker.io, it might help.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll check them out.